# EF Group and sum method-based query

Tags: linq-to-entities, group-by

I have a flat table (sorry, but it's how the data comes in) and am trying to write a method-based linq query to return a list of users with their total steps. Should be pretty simple, but examples that I've found and tried are not working. Here's the class:

```
public class WellnessLog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int Steps { get; set; }
    public datetime EnteredOn { get; set; }
    public datetime StartedOn { get; set; }
    public datetime EndOn { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find any examples? Really?

Well this should work. Typically a group by is over multiple tables, but since it's just the one, it's even easier:

```
var query = db.WellnessLogs
    .GroupBy(x => x.Username)
    .Select (x => new { Username = x.Username, Steps = x.Steps.Count() });
```

Equivalent to the following T-SQL:

```
SELECT   Username, Count(Steps)
FROM     dbo.WellnessLogs
GROUP BY Username
```

Comment: I think you may have forgotten an aggregate ;)

Comment: /me slaps head. it's early, and i'm waiting for my peers so i can get my first coffee for the day. :) Updated.

Comment: Appreciate the help. Your solution provided the clues to get the query right.

Comment: @gnome - if the query above didn't work, please update your question with the query that worked or add an answer of your own, for the benefit of others who stumble onto this question.